# How to type x̂ or ŷ in Julia?

Tags: julia

I was reading through [a tutorial](https://fluxml.ai/tutorials/2021/02/07/convnet.html) and it makes use of x hat and y hat. I am unable to create those characters locally and they do not appear in the unicode character list I saw. Usually I would do `\xhat` to create the unicode character but that again does not seem to exist in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type `x\hat` and press <kbd>tab</kbd> to get what you want. You can also search the character in the Julia REPL:

```
help?> x̂
"x̂" can be typed by x\hat<tab>
```

Note that in this case this sequence consists of two characters:

```
julia> collect("x̂")
2-element Vector{Char}:
 'x': ASCII/Unicode U+0078 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
 '̂': Unicode U+0302 (category Mn: Mark, nonspacing)
```

Of which the second is a [combining diacritical mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks).